# Why This Lua's Program Didn't Compile Correctly? (EEPro)

Tags: java, compilation, lua

First I want to clarify that I am a total newbie using Lua.
My Goal is Creating a Java application using the code posted below.
I have a Lenovo Y560, which has a Windows 7 x64 operating system. I downloaded LuaForWindows_v5.1.4-46 for this purpose.
As I said, my goal is to create a Java application for mobile which has a Symbian OS S40, my idea is to turn this program in Lua to Java. But along the way I doubt there were doubts.
I apologize if I made this question incorrectly.

[EEPro for Nspire on Lua](http://github.com/adriweb/EEPro-for-Nspire/blob/master/EEPro.big.lu)

Trying to Compile this Lua's Program, I got the following Error:

```
> > lua -e "io.stdout:setvbuf 'no'" "EEPro.big.lua" 
> > lua: proyecto.big.lua:14: attempt to call field 'uchar' (a nil value)
> stack traceback:
proyecto.big.lua:14: in function 'utf8'
proyecto.big.lua:35: in main chunk
[C]: ?
```

> Exit code: 1

Could you tell me why this Happen?

Comment: Probably, this Lua code requires [Extended Standard Library](http://wiki.inspired-lua.org/Category:Extended_Standard_Library) to be installed (it seems to be installed by default on native system which this code was written for).

Comment: How to Install LuaRocks?

Comment: I got an Error in the Original Code in Line 1942, After inserting those lines.

>lua -e "io.stdout:setvbuf 'no'" "proyecto.big.lua" 
lua: proyecto.big.lua:1942: attempt to index global 'image' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
 proyecto.big.lua:1942: in main chunk
 [C]: ?
>Exit code: 1

Comment: More libraries required.  It may be not so easy to port native TI-Nspire calculator program to Java.  Lua scripts is only a part of the program.

Comment: Thank you Very Very Much Egor, for read and help me. I Will Keep Trying on future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.uchar` can be implemented this way (just insert these lines at the beginning of your`EEPro.big.lua` file):

```
function string.uchar(c, ...)
    if c then
        local t, h, s = {}, 128, string.uchar(...)
        while c >= h do
            t[#t+1] = 128 + c%64
            c = math.floor(c/64)
            h = h > 32 and 32 or h/2
        end
        t[#t+1] = 256 - 2*h + c
        return s.char((table.unpack or unpack)(t)):reverse()..s
    else
        return ''
    end
end
```